# Center content in Material UI Box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the Box content on the right (Textfields, etc.) as shown in the image below to be always centered even in responsive,

[image]

I tried `justifyContent="center"` in `<Box >` but nothing happened it didn't move at all also tried `justifyContent="center"` in `<Stack >` also nothing happened, I'm not sure if I missed something or there is another way to do it!!
Some help would be appreciated.

**The code:**

```
return (
    <div className="login">
      <Box>
      <Stack direction="row" 
      // spacing={1} > 
      
        {/* FIRST BOX ON THE LEFT WITH THE IMAGE & LOGO */}
        <Box sx={{
              width: "40%",
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: '#3AAFA9',
              display: {xs: "none", md: "none", sm: "none", lg:"block"},
              }}
              >
              
              {/* TO HOLD IMAGE, LOGO & DISCRIPTION */}
            <Stack direction="column"
            spacing={-2}
            sx={{ display: 'block' }}
            py={10}
            ml={7}>
            {/* STUFF */}
            </Stack>
            
        </Box>
       
        {/* HERE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS*/}
        <Box component="div" 
            //   sx= {{
            //     padding:{ xs: 2, sm: 4, md: 4, lg:10 },
            // }}
            justifyContent= "center">
          <Stack
          direction='column'
          width="100%"
          justifyContent="flex-start"
          // sx={{ ml: 10 }}
          >
                  
          <Typography variant="h5" 
          gutterBottom 
          component="span"
          style={{ fontWeight: 600, textAlign: 'left' }}
          >
          Login to 
          </Typography>

          <Divider style={{width:'100%'}}>
            Or
            </Divider>

      {/* LOGIN FORM */}
      <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      
      </form>
      {/* LOGIN FORM ENDS */}
      
          </Stack>
          </Box>
      </Stack>
      </Box>
      </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box-Component of Mui dont have a prop justifyContent.
You have to declare it inside youre sx.

```
sx={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%",
    //...
}}
```

The width is just to say the box it have to use the hole space.

Cheers